# Jboss 7.1 - server.log gets created without world-read access

Tags: jboss

On our systems running JBoss 6.1, server.log is always created (every night) with protections of 664.

But on our server running JBoss 7.1, server.log gets created with protections of 600

Without world-read or group-read protections, Nagios can't look for errors.

I assume this is set somewhere in jboss-logging.xml somehow.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

File permissions are determined by the user's `umask`, there's not a way to change it in logger itself.

Check the `umask` for the user that used to run JBoss

```
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx
```

Check the JBoss startup script, search calls to `umask` command.